# Is there a way to use css variable without inline style?

Tags: css, vue.js, var, sanitization, inline-styles

**My goal:** To style a link, that comes from a sanitized text, with a css variable. Im using a vue framework and want to use a computed style(or similar) to style it. The color of the link comes from an api.

**My issue:** Since the text is sanitized, no inline style will come through. I can still access the link like this:

```
.sub-link-style >>> a {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

But I can't use the variable because I cannot add inline stlye.

**My question:** Is there a way to add a custom value(for example from vue) to a css variable without inline style?

Comment: Consulting a reference as a first step might be handy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties (so yes, there is as “[custom properties are] written inside a ruleset”; inline or not)

Comment: You can use a constructed stylesheet (along with the polyfill).

Comment: If you aren't allowed to add an inline style (and it might be useful to know why not) are you allowed to add anything - like another style element to the head element?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! :) @AHaworth  I am allowed to add inline styles, but the sanitizer will remove any inline style for security reasons. The only way i can access it is through a css ruleset, like the one in the code block.

Comment: So can you add another style element to the head through eg JavaScript at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue became using the sanitizers custom handler to create an exception for the attribute i needed specifically.

However, it only left me with a new problem. When the text gets into the code the computed variables are already resolved. Given up on it for now. Perhaps I'll look more at it later.